# JointEffortController only show command topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using gazebo RRBot Example with ros_control, as the follow tutorial:
[http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control]

the rrbot has two joints, joint1 and joint2.
I changed joint2 controller from *effort_controllers/JointPositionController* to *effort_controllers/JointEffortController*
when I run it, I found the joint2 only have one */rrbot/joint2_effort_controller/command* topic, that was different from joint1.
I want to know is it was ok?
[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241294/jointeffortcontroller-only-show-command-topic/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have referred to baxter simulator, and find it is may be right in effort control

---

Originally posted by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) with karma: 58 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0